# SQL inner join select field list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, 1 is called `menu` and 1 is called `orderregel`. 
An `orderregel` is a database table used in stores to store specific products and the amount.

I have this for menus in a restaurant, people can order different menus and they will all get their own orderregel which then is added to an order which you pay at the end.

So I want to see the the menus which are chosen per table and the amount they are chosen.

Here are the 2 tables:

```
|---------------------|-------------------------|
|        Menu         |        Orderregel       |
|---------------------|-------------------------|
|  ID  |     Name     | ID | Quantity | Menu_id |
|---------------------|-------------------------|
|  1   |   Menu One   | 1  |     3    |    1    |
|  2   |   Menu two   | 2  |     2    |    1    | 
|  3   |   Menu Three | 3  |     4    |    3    | 
|---------------------|-------------------------|
```

And with a SQL query I want to get this result:

```
|---------------------|
|  Result of query    |
|---------------------|
| Menu Name|Quantity  |
|---------------------|
| Menu One |    5     |
| Menu Two |    0     | 
|Menu Three|    4     | 
|---------------------|
```

The SQL query I currently have is:

```
SELECT SUM(orderregel.aantal) AS Aantal 
FROM `orderregel` 
WHERE menu_id IS NOT null 
GROUP BY menu_id
```

Which will give me this result

```
|---------------------|
|  Result of query    |
|---------------------|
|      Quantity       |
|---------------------|
|         5           | 
|         4           | 
|---------------------|
```

I am now trying to figure out a query which will get the name and the quantity as shown in the table above this one. What i tried to do is this :

```
SELECT menu.naam, quantity.aantal 
FROM `menu` 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT sum(orderregel.aantal) AS aantal 
    FROM orderregel 
    WHERE menu_id IS NOT null 
    GROUP BY menu_id) AS quantity
```

But this query will give me duplicates in a weird way, like this:

```
|---------------------|
|  Result of query    |
|---------------------|
| Menu Name|Quantity  |
|---------------------|
| Menu One |    5     |
| Menu Two |    0     | 
|Menu Three|    5     | 
| Menu One |    4     |
| Menu Two |    0     | 
|Menu Three|    4     | 
|---------------------|
```

Do you have a solution? Thanks

**EDIT 1**
I forgot to mention i use MySQL and i tried to LEFT JOIN and OUTER JOIN which both give the erro 1062

**EDIT 2**

```
SELECT menu.naam as 'Menu naam', sum(orderregel.aantal) as Aantal 
FROM `menu` 
LEFT JOIN orderregel on menu.id = orderregel. menu_id 
WHERE order_id = '57' 
GROUP BY menu_id
```

the order_id = '57' will be changed in my code to a variable based on the selected order/customer. Thank you guys for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking to your tables you should only permform a select with group by

```
  SELECT menu.name, sum(orderregel.quantity)    as quantity
  FROM `menu` 
  INNER JOIN orderregel
  on menu.menu_id = orderregel. menu_id
  group by menu_id
```

or if the join clause don't always match use left join

```
  SELECT menu.name, sum(orderregel.quantity)    as quantity
  FROM `menu` 
  LEFT JOIN orderregel
  on menu.menu_id = orderregel. menu_id
  group by menu_id
```

Comment: The key is the `outer join`... (I didn't downvote you though)

Answer (score 2):

Use an `outer join` instead:

```
select m.id, m.name, coalesce(sum(o.quantity),0) as quantity
from menu m
    left join orderregel o on m.id = o.menu_id
group by m.id, m.name
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: @danny117 -- the `sum` of `null` is `null`, not `0`.  That's why I used `coalesce`... See this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edf0d/1

Comment: Ah i see, but my quantity has a NOT NULL in the database so its always 0. There are also restrictions in the code which enfore a 1 or above quantity

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer -- run it without the `coalesce` and the `sum` will return `null`... it doesn't matter that it has a `not null` constraint, the `sum` of no records is `null`, not `0`. the key is the `outer join` though.

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer -- it won't error, it will just display as `null`.  See this fiddle from my previous comment: sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edf0d/1

Comment: ah i see, but in my application and also in phpmyadmin it does not show the menu where quantity is 0 somehow. So good for me

Answer (score 1):

I think a left join would achieve what you need. Left join will output all the rows of the left-hand (first) table).

```
SELECT menu.id, menu.naam, SUM(orderregel.aantal) AS Aantal 
FROM `menu`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `orderregel` on menu.id = orderregel.menu_id
WHERE menu_id IS NOT null 
GROUP BY menu.id, menu.naam
```

P.S. I'm guessing in reality you will want to restrict this by customer as well, otherwise you'll just get the number of menus ordered by everyone in the restaurant.

Comment: Yeh true I want it by customer, but I can do that part myself i think

Answer (score 0):

```
select name,sum(quantity) as quantity 
 from
 Menu  join Orderrege1 as O
on menu.ID = O.menu_id group by Menu.Name
```